# \sum in text mode when inserted in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I have the following line of code :

```
$$
\operatorname{aff}(\mathcal{C})
\coloneqq
\{
\lambda_{1}x_{1}+\lambda_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}x_{k}
\mid 
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k}\in\mathcal{C},\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}=1
\}
$$
```

which should generate the following expression :

[image]

I wish to know if there is a way to replace the summation notation above and replace it with the smaller summation notation used in text mode i.e. the one below :

```
$\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}$
```

[image]

I attempted to use `\text{$\sum_{i}$}` in math mode but it did not work because it gave me the large summation notation.

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\textstyle`.

And use `\[\]` instead of `$$ $$` for display style math.

**Improved Answer** (modification according to Zarko's and egreg's comments):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\operatorname{aff}(\mathcal{C})
\coloneqq
\{
\lambda_{1}x_{1}+\lambda_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}x_{k}
\mid
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k}\in\mathcal{C},{\textstyle\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}}=1
\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

- Removed the `amsmath` package as it is loaded by the `mathtools` package (mentioned by zarko).
- Grouped the part that is to be displayed by `\textstyle` in the text style mode as `\textstyle` is not a macro (mentioned by egreg).

**Original Problametic answer:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\[
\operatorname{aff}(\mathcal{C})
\coloneqq
\{
\lambda_{1}x_{1}+\lambda_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}x_{k}
\mid
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k}\in\mathcal{C},\textstyle{\sum_{i}\lambda_{i}}=1
\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `mathtools` call ``amsmath``, so you not need to load it again. Also definition for new operator name is better to have in preamble.

Comment: Note that `\textstyle` doesn't take an argument: it's a declaration whose effect ends with the formula.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko for your suggestion. I have tried to edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @egreg for your suggestion. I have tried to edit accordingly. (Can't mention 2 in a single comment!)

Answer (score 8):

For a one-off case you can use [Zarko's method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628141/4427).

If you need it several times, you can define a command that forces text style when the symbol is to be used in display style. However, I'd also use `\big` size for the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\aff}{aff}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tsum}{\DOTSB\mathop{\tsum@}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\tsum@}{\mathchoice{\textstyle\sum}{\sum}{\sum}{\sum}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\aff{\mathcal{C}}\coloneqq
\bigr\{
  \lambda_{1}x_{1}+\lambda_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}x_{k}
  \mid
  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k}\in\mathcal{C},\tsum_{i}\lambda_{i}=1
\bigr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A wee bit modified @Imran answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\aff}{aff} % <---

\begin{document}
\[
\aff(\mathcal{C})\coloneqq
\bigl\{  % <---
\lambda_{1}x_{1}+\lambda_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+\lambda_{k}x_{k}
\mid
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{k}\in\mathcal{C},{\textstyle\sum_{i}}\lambda_{i}=1 % <---
\bigr\}   % <---
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]